# Email Sending in java ( working in local) (Spring MVC)

Tags: java, email, spring-mvc, cloudbees

I'm sending email to get my user details. It is working in localhost. It sends the email but when i deployed it to cloudbees, i got this error. Do you know guys whats happening here? I'll be grateful if you help me. This is the last module in my project.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbuM2
534-5.7.14 qusylLyBGwv6C0LXTQk55UH7xMvqM3XLGT49bIoOTUB2-KJE8sMw3fGu4C9ofzO5ypepa-
534-5.7.14 qNUIoJFvfobZbjK1d0jGGPyLFhA-top_G0izi7b5a50upMEqyAZPsEBJByxXXkzBD8yghK
534-5.7.14 00fsqA4V4Q_qrczaPtrsz5yGASMne_rX0sT3X_lzkDrB1zcldraPKw1CiENYroBd4POGme
534-5.7.14 eCS5vNA> Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
534-5.7.14 Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=787
534 5.7.14 54 o11sm76701768qay.39 - gsmtp

    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

Comment: `AuthenticationException`, check out differences between local/cloudbees, any reason non-local authentication would fail?

Comment: i guess itd not able to Authenticate credentials you have provided. are you sure you are using the right host server

Comment: i got the same code. same user credentials to my email. i just don't know why its not sending in non-local.

Comment: btw im using spring 4

Comment: This is interesting: https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbuM2. Do you use two factor passwords? You may need authenticate another server.

Comment: i have a lot of email sending in my app. it works in the other modules of my email sending but it doesn't work in this one.. btw. this module is forgotpassword.

Comment: Afaik, Google have to allow your app to use your own account: go to https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and within some minutes google should be able to remember the application/service and allow your application to access your account (see here http://email.about.com/od/gmailtips/qt/How-To-Unlock-Gmail-For-A-New-Email-Program-Or-Service.htm.) However, an easier way is to use a cloud-based email infrastructure and delivery service such as SendGrid. At cloudbees you can find several examples on how to use it (i.e https://github.com/CloudBees-community/tomcat7-sendgrid-clickstart)

Comment: thanks. i can't solve the issue. i already tried displayunlock. i did the sendgrid part.

Answer (score 1):

By default Gmail account is highly secured. When we use gmail smtp from non gmail tool, email is blocked.  To test in our local environment, make your gmail account less secure as

1. Login to Gmail.
2. Access the URL as https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
3. Select "Turn on"